# get value of string before and after / in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

suppose i have 10 localstorage like blow:

```js
localStorage.setItem("item01","this is a value/100");
localStorage.setItem("item02","this new is a value/110");
localStorage.setItem("item03","this is a good value/120");
localStorage.setItem("item04","this is a nice value/130");
```

I need a java script code to check if the `key` of for example `item01` is not 0 then put the `data` of `item01` before `/` to `xyz` and the data after `/` to `rfv` variable.

Comment: You can use store json data in the localStorage using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, which will give you better control of the data you're serializing

Comment: use value.split("/")

Comment: *"I need a java script code to..."* Okay. When you run into trouble writing that, come back with a specific question about the problem you're having. SO is not a code-writing service, but we're very happy to help **you** write the code.

Comment: got it T.J. Crowder ;)

Comment: thanks .  kasper Taeymans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suppose you split the data-string along the character "/". Something like:

```
var lsData = localStorage.getItem("item01");
var dataArray = lsData.split("/");

if(dataArray.length === 2){
  var xyz = dataArray[0];
  var rfv = dataArray[1];
}
else{ 
  ... error-code (could not split exactly)... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to your question "get value of string before and after / in javascript". 
Like I stated in the comments you can [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) a string into an array of substrings using a delimiter.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/wrdp3bhk/1/)

```
var str= "this is a value/100";
var temp=str.split("/");

var xyz = temp[0]; //->this is a value
var rfv = temp[1]; //->100

alert('xyz = '+xyz+'\nrfv = '+rfv);
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it...

I'm assuming you know how to get the localStorage value, so I'm just posting an example.

```
var a = "this is a value/100"

var b = /^(.*?)\/(\w+)/.exec(a);
var text = b[1]
var value = b[2]
```